# React scroll animation with setState is choppy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, css-animations

It's seems use `setState` to animate elements by listening to `window.scrollY` would make very choppy effect.

```
const scrollY = window.scrollY;

animation01: {
  transformY: (scrollY > breakPoint01) ? `translateY(200px)` : `translateY(0px)`,
},
```

I ended up with the solution of `ref` to manipulate DOM directly to avoid the choppy effect...

```
const breakPoint00 = 1250
const breakPoint01 = breakPoint00 + 230
const animation01 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.animation01)

if (scrollY > breakPoint00) {
  animation01.style.transform = `translateY(0px)`
} else (scrollY > breakPoint01) {
  animation01.style.transform = `translateY(200px)`
}
```

Why is it so choppy when using the first solution? Is this a right way to do scrolling animation in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking - **Yes**, you should use `ref` to animate or change style properties with events like scroll, zoom etc. The reason is because when you use `setState` you force to rerender component every time you scroll, zoom etc. In addition these events can be called many many times per second, so you can imagine why you get *choppy* effects.

However, when you change css directly component does not rerender - it only changes style right on the element, so you animation effect is more smoothly.

**EDIT**

So I decided to create a little demo that illustrates what've been asked in comments under the answer.

Here is [jsfiddle little demo](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)

It behaves as you would update component. You can easily check it by inserting `console.log('updated')` inside `componentDidUdpate` hook - every time you invoke `setState` you'll see `updated` message. It does not *remounts* component though.

Comment: Thank you explaining! For rerendering component, do you mean the component `unmount` and `mount` again and again? Or it simply just compare with virtual DOM and update a certain node?

Comment: @TzuYuanLiu I've updated my answer. Hope demo will help you better understand what is going on when `setState` is called.